# logrotate does not produce any output

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, logrotate

I set up a logrotate configuration file containing containing two entries. the file contains the following:

```
/var/www/designer-24.com/var/log/* {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    dateext
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}

/var/www/designer-24.com/var/report/* {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    dateext
    notifempty
    copytruncate
}
```

Then I run the following command

```
sudo logrotate -s /var/log/logstatus logrotate.conf
```

The files get registered in the logstatus files. However, when I access the directory containing the files to be logrotated, I do not see any copies of the files except the original ones, and are not emptied.

Can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> SOLUTION: I added the following to each entry
>
> ```
> su www-data www-data
> ```
>
> Turns out it was a permissions issue